# How to use elevate-zoom in Angular 5?

Tags: jquery, html, angular, angular5, elevatezoom

[A Jquery Image Zoom Plugin](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom)

I am using `elevate-zoom` jquery plugin in my angular 5 app but it's showing error

> ERROR TypeError: this.elevatezoomBig.nativeElement.elevateZoom is not
>   a function

[image]

Here's my code

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class ProductComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        @ViewChild('elevatezoomBig') elevatezoomBig : ElementRef;

        this.elevatezoomBig.nativeElement.elevateZoom({
            borderSize: 1,
            lensFadeIn: 200,
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            zoomWindowFadeIn: 200,
            loadingIcon: true,
            zoomWindowOffety: -50,
            zoomWindowOffetx: 50,
            zoomWindowHeight: 530,
            responsive: true
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, when using jQuery plugins pay attention to two things:

1. every event that happens (every one) is going to trigger a change detection. So if the jQuery plugin is not "educated" you risk to incur in performance issues. To attenuate this, you can run jQuery code "outside Angular".
2. it's still a jQuery plugin, so you should use the global jQuery object to access it.

Having said that, I would try the following:

```
// this line tells TypeScript that something called "$" exists
declare let $: any;

// I'm assuming you omitted the "component" declaration
export class ProductComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

    @ViewChild('elevatezoomBig') elevatezoomBig : ElementRef;

    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            $(this.elevatezoomBig.nativeElement).elevateZoom({
                borderSize: 1,
                lensFadeIn: 200,
                cursor: 'crosshair',
                zoomWindowFadeIn: 200,
                loadingIcon: true,
                zoomWindowOffety: -50,
                zoomWindowOffetx: 50,
                zoomWindowHeight: 530,
                responsive: true
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Edit: the syntax `constructor(private ngZone: NgZone)` lets you declare a property named `ngZone` and whose value is automatically set to the value of the constructor's parameter `ngZone`. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) under **Parameter Properties**.

When you use a jQuery plugin, you need the DOM to be already processed. The instantiation of a component (the so called life cycle) follows three basic steps: constructor -> the runtime fills in input properties -> `ngOnInit` -> the template is processed and the DOM initialized -> `ngOnAfterViewInit`. If you don't know very well this sequence, do yourself a favor and read [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) as soon as you can. Trust me, you'll thank me later.

Having said this, we need to call the plugin initialization code in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: Thank you chiesa for quick reply but i am use both OnInit and AfterViewInit and it's showing error. 
`Module parse failed: The keyword 'private' is reserved (88:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         this.galleryTop.swiper.params.control = this.galleryThumbs.swiper;
|         this.galleryThumbs.swiper.params.control = this.galleryTop.swiper;
|         constructor(private, ngZone, core_1.NgZone);
|         {
|             ngZone.runOutsideAngular(function () {`

Comment: I edited my previous answer. You have to have the `private ngZone: NgZone` in the constructor, and the plugin initialization code in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: I have tried this, an error was gone but the function is not working.

Comment: Well, I think you should try to produce a minimal reproducible example with the error, so we can work on it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It is impossible to fully reconstruct your problem without seeing it.